# How to apply a function to the value of a tensor and then assigning the output to the same tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I want to project the updated weights of my network (after performing optimization) to a special space in which I need the value of that tensor to be passed. The function which applies projection gets a numpy array as an input. Is there a way I can do this?

I used tf.assign() as a solution but since my function accepts arrays and not tensors it failed.

Here is a sketch of what I want to do:

```
W = tf.Variable(...)
...
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, var_list=['W'])
W = my_function(W)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `tf.control_dependencies` is what you need

one simple exmaple:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var = tf.get_variable('var', initializer=0.0)
# replace `tf.add` with your custom function 
addop = tf.add(var, 1)  

with tf.control_dependencies([addop]):
    updateop = tf.assign(var, addop)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  # pylint: disable=no-member
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    updateop.eval()
    print(var.eval())
    updateop.eval()
    print(var.eval())
    updateop.eval()
    print(var.eval())
```

output:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

Comment: The function I want to use is in another library which gets a real array as input not tensor.